# Matching elements by contents works in console, fails "in real life"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide video results from known bad channels on YouTube. It shouldn't be very challenging. Video items mainly come in two variants of `span`: larger `.result-item`s when searching videos and smaller `.video-list-item`s for the related videos column. Both have the channel owner listed inside their inner `.yt-user-name` element.

Through some mucking around with Chrome 20's developer console I found the following to work as expected:

1. Start from [any page with search results](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=meet%20the%20pyro), inject jQuery
2. Select the first search result with `a = $(".video-list-item, .result-item")[0]`
3. Extract the username and convert it to lowercase with `$(a).find(".yt-user-name").text().toLowerCase()`

Thus I tried the following:

```
badChannels = ["vaivecorporation"] #fill in as desired

$(jQuery.grep($(".video-list-item, .result-item"),
  function(item, number){
    username = $(item).find(".yt-username").text().toLowerCase();
    console.debug(username);
    return badChannels.indexOf(username) != -1;
  })).css('opacity', 0.1);
```

Despite the copious amount of jQuery, which is perfect and does all things, injecting [the latest jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) and the above in [here](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=meet%20the%20pyro) simply gives me 24 newlines.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've been using [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plcnnpdmhobdfbponjpedobekiogmbco) to do the injecting work [like this](http://i.imgur.com/wjX8M.png); I'm sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick wee look through the page source, it looks like you need `yt-user-name`, and not `yt-username`

Comment: FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU